# Template haskell type list

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Is there a way to construct type level lists using `'[Foo, Bar, Maybe Quux]` syntax?

It's possible to do:

```
promotedTypeList :: [Q Type] -> Q Type
promotedTypeList []     = promotedNilT
promotedTypeList (t:ts) = [t| $promotedConsT $t $(promotedTypeList ts) |]
```

But that will result into very ugly haddocks:

```
type Example = (:) [*] ((:) * Foo ((:) * Bar ((:) * (Maybe Quux) ([] *)))) ([] [*])
```

---

*EDIT:*

Haddock / GHC is smart enough to print types (almost) how user typed them:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module T (Foo, Bar) where

type Foo = Int ': Bool ': Char ': '[]
type Bar = '[ Int, Bool, Char ]
```

[image: GHC 7.8]
[image: GHC 7.10]

---

Smallest example where issue is shown is at https://gist.github.com/phadej/f92e84a1f03ffb414ab4

Comment: That syntax correponds exactly to that type, i.e. `'[X, Y]` is exactly the same as `X ': Y ': '[]`. The former is simply syntactic sugar. The way the list is printed depends not on template haskell, but on the pretty printer used by GHC (or in this case, Haddock). Old versions of GHC will print type operators as prefix functions, and will include the *kind* arguments to the type function. I don't know what version of Haddock you are using, but I imagine this to be a bug - it was fixed in GHC a while back.

Comment: @user2407038 the GHC prints types as programmer (in this case template-haskell) has written them. I.e. I'd like to type `'[X, Y]`, but cannot with template-haskell  Thus GHC sees `X ': Y ': []` only. The infix version in haddocks without kinds is already an improvement, so if someone can confirm that it will be so, say in GHC 8.0, I'd be happy.

Comment: "GHC prints types as programmer has written them" While this is generally true, it isn't the case for type level lists. Define `type X = '[ Int, Bool, Char ]` and `type Y = Int ': Bool ': Char ': '[]` and ask for their kind or info (`:kind!` or `:i`) and it will print them both with the special list syntax. In fact you can write `:kind! forall x . (x ': x ': x ': '[])` and ghc 7.8 and 7.10 give me `forall (k :: BOX) (x :: k). '[x, x, x]`.

Comment: @user2407038 I don't care that much about ghci, but about haddock documentation. See edit in the question.

Comment: It seems to be a haddock issue, opened issue in haddock tracker: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/466

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that TH will splice in the lifted type list *incorrectly* when you write the function `promotedTypeList` the way you have it written. In other words, the function generates a different representation of the list than creating and splicing a type level list directly. Here is a simple test to see this.

First define the TH functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-} 

module TH where 
import Language.Haskell.TH 

typeList0, typeList1 :: [Q Type] -> Q Type
typeList0 = foldr (\x xs -> appT (appT promotedConsT x) xs) promotedNilT 
typeList1 = foldl (\xs x -> [t| $x ': $xs |]) promotedNilT T
```

There are two variants - one does what you want and the other doesn't. To see precisely why, you can look at the splices:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-} 
{-# OPTIONS -ddump-splices #-} 

module Test where 

import Language.Haskell.TH (stringE, Type(..))
import TH (typeList0, typeList1)

ex1 = $(typeList0 (map (return.ConT) [ ''Int, ''Bool, ''Char ]) >>= stringE . show) 
ex2 = $(typeList1 (map (return.ConT) [ ''Int, ''Bool, ''Char ]) >>= stringE . show) 

type Ex1 = $(typeList0 (map (return.ConT) [ ''Int, ''Bool, ''Char ]))
type Ex2 = $(typeList1 (map (return.ConT) [ ''Int, ''Bool, ''Char ]))
```

With `haddock -h Test.hs TH.hs` you get (the interesting bits)

```
Test.hs:12:9-82: Splicing expression
    typeList0 (map (return . ConT) [''Int, ''Bool, ''Char])
    >>= stringE . show
  ======>
    "AppT (AppT PromotedConsT (ConT GHC.Types.Int)) (AppT (AppT PromotedConsT (ConT GHC.Types.Bool)) (AppT (AppT PromotedConsT (ConT GHC.Types.Char)) PromotedNilT))"

Test.hs:13:9-82: Splicing expression
    typeList1 (map (return . ConT) [''Int, ''Bool, ''Char])
    >>= stringE . show
  ======>
    "AppT (AppT (PromotedT GHC.Types.:) (ConT GHC.Types.Char)) (AppT (AppT (PromotedT GHC.Types.:) (ConT GHC.Types.Bool)) (AppT (AppT (PromotedT GHC.Types.:) (ConT GHC.Types.Int)) PromotedNilT))"
```

As you can plainly see, the two simply have *different representations*. The latter representation encodes the lifted list constructors as the application of a `PromotedT` constructor to the normal list constructors. I guess Haddock simply can't deal with this.

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: If I modify your version to ` [t| $promotedConsT $x $xs |]) promotedNil` I'll get `Ex1` and `Ex2` to print the same. Now I wonder why it doesn;t work with `generics-sop`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/phadej/f92e84a1f03ffb414ab4 is the smallest example where I can reproduce it. Something weird happens with `tySynInstD`, which doesn't happen with `tySynD`.